# Create volume with docker volume with a custom Mountpoint

Tags: docker, docker-volume, mount-point

I need to create a volume with "docker volume" with a personal Mountpoint (mountpoint="/my/path/  not  /var/lib/docker...) but i can't use plugin like local-persist

```
docker volume create -d local-persist -o mountpoint=/data/images --name=images
```

i need something like this but without plugin, maybe it can be done with --opt= and somethig after that, but i'm new at docker and linux.
I hope someone can help me, just pay attention: i need "docker volume create" not something that let me use personal path in docker-compose.yml or something like this.

Edit

my docker compose is something like

```
version: '3.1'

services:

  grafana:
    image: grafana/grafana:5.3.4
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    volumes:
      - grafanasql:/var/lib/grafana
      - grafanaconf:/etc/grafana
  ...
  ...
  volumes:
    grafanasql:
      external: true
    grafanaconf:
      external: true
```

If i let docker create volumes all its ok, but when i try to use external volume, with your docker volume create it doesnt work.

Answer (score 6):

The syntax is

```
docker volume create -d local -o o=bind -o device=/your/path
```

Or in `docker-compose`

```
volumes:
  mydata:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      o: bind
      device: /your/path
```

Comment: i try it but when i inspect the volume "pippo" the mountpoint is always the same /var/lib/docker/volumes....., and when i try to use this volume it doesnt work

Comment: Yes `Mountpoint` is still that, but `docker run -v volume_just_created:/test ubuntu ls /test` will return the content of `/your/path`

Comment: i add my docker-compose too explain better my throuble.

Comment: I also had to add `type: none` to `driver_opts` (docker-compose v3.2).